# PR controller electrical circuit

Tags: control-system

I am attempting to design a PR control feedback loop for a grid tie inverter. The math checks out but I can't seem to convert the transfer function and/or block diagram into an actual electrical circuit. Please find the block and transfer function attached. I would like to get an op amp circuit to implement this [image: block diagram]

Answer (score 2):

Normally you would find an op amp topology such as a sallen key:

[image]

which the transfer function would be

$$ H(s)=\frac{Z_3Z_4}{Z_1Z_2+Z_3(Z_1+Z_2)+Z_3Z_4}$$

And typically resistors \$ Z_x(s)=R\$ and capacitors \$ Z_x(s)=\frac{1}{Cs}\$ are used in these types of active filters.

There are also other realizable transfer functions that you can build with op amps:

[image]
Source: slideplayer.com

However the transfer function you supplied is not realizable with general filters:

$$ H(s)=\frac{Ks}{s^2+w^2} \neq \frac{Z_3Z_4}{Z_1Z_2+Z_3(Z_1+Z_2)+Z_3Z_4}$$

because there is a middle term in the polynomial, no combination of high pass or low pass filters can used to construct your desired loop.

I will say this, an integrator is achieved this way with opamps:

[image]
Source: electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_6.html

$$ H(s)=\frac{1}{sRC}$$

So you could use that in your top and bottom portion of the loop.

If your looking to simply shift the frequency, then use a [PLL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked_loop), [described here](http://www.electronics-tutorial.net/analog-integrated-circuits/phase-locked-loop/index.html). Or a circuit such as an orthogonal [signal generator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/215682/orthogonal-singal-generator)

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a Second Order Generalized Integrator (SOGI). In LTspice, it would look like this:

[image: sogi]

Time domain response:

[image: time]

Frequency response:

[image: freq]

`G1, R1` form the error amplifier, `G2, C1` the first integrator, and `G3, C2` the second. These are, usually, implemented in a DSP, since the control is done digitally, and since you'd normally need several stages of these, one for each harmonic.

There are several version of a SOGI, this one is the simplest, yours looks like it allows for correction with external \$\omega t\$ signal, others have a stabilized loop, other corrections, etc.

Comment: That's a strange looking op-amp.

Comment: @HarrySvensson It's a behavioural model, since I've mentioned that, usually, they're implemented in DSP software. But, yes, that's an integrator, and nobody says an integrator must be with an opamp.

Comment: By the way, this could be done with a single bv-source. Or if you really need the signals, three bv-sources.

Comment: @laptop2d I know, but the whole point is getting the signals, because it outputs a quadrature (the outputs of each integrator).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Can you elaborete for a novice: What do these symbols (apparently not op-amps) represent? My best guess is like an op-amp but with a current output instead of voltage?

Comment: @flawr The voltage across a capacitor is the integral of the current though it, and together with the VCCS acts as an integrator (input voltage converted to current, integrated by the capacitor, voltage output). `G1` and `R1` are the equivalent of a VCVS (voltage controlled voltage source), a simpe gain.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense! Are there any actual ICs that implement a voltage controlled current source? (So far I've only found circuits using op-amps to do this.)

Comment: @flawr A VCCS is nothing but a transconductance, so anything like the old LM13700 will do. Don't forget that the picture above is the ideal, behavioural schematic for a SOGI. As mentioned, in practice this is done in a DSP, because the quadrature is exact (within numerical limits), as opposed to an analog version which can have tolerances all over the place.

Comment: @VoltageSpike I have no idea how I missed your comment, but I did. With late regards, yes, it could have been done that way, but somehow I doubt the OP would have understood much of it.