# Bubba Oscillator - Last filter not buffered

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, oscillator, low-pass, buffer

Let's say that we have the following circuit of a Bubba Oscillator[image]

The purpose of the four low pass filters is to achieve a 45 degrees phase shift in the oscillation frequency. Meanwhile, the three op amps used (excluding the first one that implements an amplifier in inverting configuration) work as buffers in order for each filter stage to not load the other ones and make them independent. My question is, why don't we add another op amp after the last low pass filter in the bottom-left corner? Doesn't the load leakage in the amplifier affect the operation of the last filter?

Thanks for any answer in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right: RG does affect the low-pass that it's connected to. In particular, it slightly increases its cut-off frequency (since RG effectively goes to ground) and it also decreases the signal amplitude by a tiny amount. The latter effect is irrelevant since it's compensated by the amplifier.

The change in cut-off frequency is quite real, though. However, this also doesn't matter in practice: The tolerances of real-world capacitors are much larger than the small shift in oscillation frequency caused by RG. R/RG is roughly 0.03, so the cut-off frequency of that lower left low-pass is increased by 3%. Typical capacitors have 10% or even 20% tolerance. Expensive ones might get you down to 5% or even 1%. You'll have to trim this circuit in any case if you want an accurate frequency, which is why the small error introduced by RG is acceptable.

This is also the reason why RG and RF are so large compared to the other resistors: It keeps its influence on the frequency response low.

Since OpAmps usually come in packages of four, adding another buffer stage would mean that you'd *double* the number of chips in the design for a negligible improvement in performance which might even be completely negated by component tolerances. It's simply not worth the additional chip.

If you want no error without any additional buffer stages, you could also set RG=2R and replace the resistor in the lower left low-pass with RG. That way, the Thevenin equivalent of the resistors in that low-pass is exactly R and the frequency response of all four low-passes in the oscillator will be identical. You'll have to increase the inverting amplifier's gain, though, to account for the additional attenuation caused by lowering RG.

Comment: @AnastassisKapetanakis If quadrature is what you want then you're better off using a [SOGI](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/369448/95619); you'll only need three opamps.

Answer (score 1):

The loading of the leftmost filter caused by Rg shifts the frequency of 45 degrees phase lag about 1/36 th part.That's compensated by the oscillation frequency shift so that the total phase shift in filters is still 180 degrees. There's 3 other filters which together have 3 steeper phase shift vs frequency dependence than the leftmost, so the oscillation frequency would shift much less, about 0,5%. Component tolerances would cause much more, so one can well ignore the loading effect. besides 4 opamps are available as one IC, 5 need one IC more.